# Flutter Load Indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => LoaderState();
}

class LoaderState extends State<Loader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1200), vsync: this);
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut);
    animation.addListener(() {
      this.setState(() {});
    });
    animation.addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {});
    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 3.0,
          width: animation.value * 100.0,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue[300],
          height: 3.0,
          width: animation.value * 75.0,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 3.0,
          width: animation.value * 50.0,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}    

Expanded(
            child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0, top: 20.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => FirstScreen()));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            height: 45.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xFF1976D2),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
                            child: Text('Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: How can I combine a class that creates a loading indicator with my button, so that when I press it, the indicator turns on and flips to the next page

Comment: You must take into account that when you press your button, the transition to the next route occurs immediately. So, unless you have another task that you want to complete before the transition (fetching or saving something on the server, etc..), it doesn't have much sense to have a loader there. Though I may also have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Your comment should be part of the question